# How to read the request body with spring webflux

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm using Spring 5, Netty and Spring webflux to develop and API Gateway. Sometime I want the request to be stopped by the gateway but I also want to read the body of the request to log it for example and return an error to the client.

I try to do this in a WebFilter by subscribing to the body.

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
    if (enabled) {
        logger.debug("gateway is enabled. The Request is routed.");
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    } else {
        logger.debug("gateway is disabled. A 404 error is returned.");

        exchange.getRequest().getBody().subscribe();
        exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Mono.just(exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().allocateBuffer(0)));
    }
}
```

When I do this it works when the content of the body is small. But when I have a large body, only the first element of the flux is read so I can't have the entire body. Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: To get request-body you can easily use the CacheRequestBody feature, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75182399/6157415

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is that you are subscribing manually within the filter, which means you're disconnecting the reading of the request from the rest of the pipeline. Calling `subscribe()` gives you a `Disposable` that helps you manage the underlying `Subscription`.

So you need to turn connect the whole process as a single pipeline, a bit like:

```
Flux<DataBuffer> requestBody = exchange.getRequest().getBody();
// decode the request body as a Mono or a Flux
Mono<String> decodedBody = decodeBody(requestBody); 
exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
return decodedBody.doOnNext(s -> logger.info(s))
                  .then(exchange.getResponse().setComplete());
```

Note that decoding the whole request body as a `Mono` means your gateway will have to buffer the whole request body in memory.

`DataBuffer` is, on purpose, a low level type. If you'd like to decode it (i.e. implement the sample `decodeBody`method) as a String, you can use one of the various `Decoder` implementations in Spring, like `StringDecoder`.

Now because this is a rather large and complex space, you can use and/or take a look at [Spring Cloud Gateway](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway), which does just that and way more.

Answer (score 7):

1.Add "**readBody()**" to the post route:

```
builder.routes()
.route("get_route", r -> r.path("/**")
    .and().method("GET")
    .filters(f -> f.filter(myFilter))
    .uri(myUrl))
.route("post_route", r -> r.path("/**")
    .and().method("POST")
    .and().readBody(String.class, requestBody -> {return true;})
    .filters(f -> f.filter(myFilter))
    .uri(myUrl))
```

2.Then you can get the body string in your filter:

```
String body = exchange.getAttribute("cachedRequestBodyObject");
```

Advantages:

1. No blocking.
2. No need to refill the body for further process.

Works with Spring Boot 2.0.6.RELEASE + Sring Cloud Finchley.SR2 + Spring Cloud Gateway.

Comment: No longer works with Greenwhich - for some reason, you get an exception caused by an empty mono being received in org.springframework.web.reactive.resource.ResourceWebHandler.lambda$handle$0(ResourceWebHandler.java:325).

Comment: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75182399/6157415) explains how to use new spring-cloud-gateway `CacheBodyRequest` feature: 
https://spring.io/blog/2023/01/18/interesting-new-filters-on-spring-cloud-gateway-4-0