# Get request body string from ServerHttpRequest / Flux<DataBuffer>

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using spring boot version - 2.0.6.RELEASE and spring cloud version - Finchley.SR2

and i have created my custom gateway filter to modify the request body.

but while converting the request body to string using Flux i am getting a empty string. i need a method to get the string corresponding to my request  body.

```
@Override
public Mono filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
    ServerHttpRequest request = (ServerHttpRequest) exchange.getRequest();
    String s = resolveBodyFromRequest(request);
     /* s comes out to be "" */
    return chain.filter(newExchange);


}



private String resolveBodyFromRequest(ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest){
    //Get the request body
    Flux<DataBuffer> body = serverHttpRequest.getBody();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    body.subscribe(buffer -> {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.readableByteCount()];
        buffer.read(bytes);
        DataBufferUtils.release(buffer);
        String bodyString = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        sb.append(bodyString);
    });
    return sb.toString();

}
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use the [ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/multi/multi__gatewayfilter_factories.html#_modify_request_body_gatewayfilter_factory) which I believe is included in Spring Cloud Gateway 2.0.2 which is part of [Finchley](https://spring.io/blog/2018/10/24/spring-cloud-finchley-sr2-is-available).

For Ex:

```
@Override
public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
   return (exchange, chain) -> {
        ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory.Config modifyRequestConfig = new ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory.Config()
                .setContentType(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.getMimeType())
                .setRewriteFunction(String.class, String.class, (exchange1, originalRequestBody) -> {
                    String modifiedRequestBody = yourMethodToModifyRequestBody(originalRequestBody);
                    return Mono.just(modifiedRequestBody);
                });

        return new ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory().apply(modifyRequestConfig).filter(exchange, chain);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is another approach work in spring cloud gateway 2.2.5, we will use ReadBodyPredicateFactory, as this will cache requestBody to ServerWebExchange with attribute key cachedRequestBodyObject

create always true Predicate

```
@Component
public class TestRequestBody implements Predicate
{
    @Override
    public boolean test(Object o)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

in application.yml, add Predicate

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
       ....
          predicates:
            .....
            - name: ReadBodyPredicateFactory
              args:
                inClass: "#{T(String)}" 
                predicate: "#{@testRequestBody}"
```

in your own filter, get requestBody like below:

```
    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Object config)
    {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {

            String requestBody = exchange.getAttribute("cachedRequestBodyObject");

        };
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

once you read(log by reading) the request body, request drops there itself. spring cloud gateway needs to record the contents of the request body, but the **request body can only be read once**. If the request body is not encapsulated after reading it , the latter service will not be able to read the body data. [follow this](https://codar.club/blogs/spring-cloud-gateway-reads-request-body-data.html)

Answer (score 3):

Refinement of @tony.hokan answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64080867/1484823 using spring cloud gateway rewrite body request to save the request body (and possibly response body) as an attribute of the `org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange`

```
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator myRouteSavingRequestBody(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
            .route("my-route-id",
                p -> p
                    .path("/v2/**") //your own path filter
                    .filters(f -> f
                        .modifyResponseBody(String.class, String.class,
                            (webExchange, originalBody) -> {
                                if (originalBody != null) {
                                    webExchange.getAttributes().put("cachedResponseBodyObject", originalBody);
                                    return Mono.just(originalBody);
                                } else {
                                    return Mono.empty();
                                }
                            })
                        .modifyRequestBody(String.class, String.class,
                            (webExchange, originalBody) -> {
                                if (originalBody != null) {
                                    webExchange.getAttributes().put("cachedRequestBodyObject", originalBody);
                                    return Mono.just(originalBody);
                                } else {
                                    return Mono.empty();
                                }
                            })

                    )
                    .uri("https://myuri.org")
            )
            .build();
    }
```

in your own filter, get requestBody like below:

```
    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Object config)
    {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {

            String requestBody = exchange.getAttribute("cachedRequestBodyObject");

        };
    }
```

Comment: You saved me a lot of time and research. Thanks a lot. You're a hero.

Answer (score 0):

From [Spring Cloud Gateway official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#the-cacherequestbody-gatewayfilter-factory):

in the **routes configuration** add Spring `CacheRequestBody` **before** your custom one:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: cache_request_body_route
        uri: lb://downstream
        predicates:
        - Path=/downstream/**
        filters:
        - name: CacheRequestBody
          args:
            bodyClass: java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

or if you are using .**properties** instead .**yaml**:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[77].filters[2]=CacheRequestBody=java.util.LinkedHashMap
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[77].filters[3]=YourCustomFilter
```

now in every filter in the chain after Spring `CacheRequestBody` you can get a **cached copy of the request body** simply calling `exchange.getAttribute(ServerWebExchangeUtils.CACHED_REQUEST_BODY_ATTR);`:

```java
@Override
public Mono filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
    LinkedHashMap<String,Object> body = exchange.getAttribute(ServerWebExchangeUtils.CACHED_REQUEST_BODY_ATTR);
    //do-stuff-with-body
    return chain.filter(exchange);
}
```