# WebClient exception due to response body consumed multiple times

Tags: java, spring, spring-webclient

It makes sense that the response body should only be consumed once. This happens in a filter that I have for logging purposes that is split over two classes/methods. Here is the filter itself:

```
public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next) {
  Logger logger = loggingHelper.loggerFor(request);
  if (loggingHelper.shouldLogRequestsAndResponses(logger)) {
    String loggingId = loggingHelper.getOrCreateCorrelationId();

    return next.exchange(request)
      .flatMap(clientResponse -> messageCreator.formatMessage(clientResponse, loggingId))
      .doOnNext(responseData ->
        logger.trace("{" + responseData.getLogMessage() + "}"))
      .map(ResponseData::getResponse);
  } else {
    return next.exchange(request);
  }
}
```

And here is the `formatMessage` from the `messageCreator`.

```
public Mono<ResponseData> formatMessage(ClientResponse response, String loggingId) {
  String responseJson = loggingUtils.createResponseLoggingJson(response, loggingId);
  ResponseData responseData = new ResponseData(response, responseJson);
  return response.bodyToMono(DataBuffer.class)
    .map(data -> {
      ClientResponse clones = response.mutate()
        .body(
          Flux.just(data))
        .build();
      String body = data.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      responseData.add("\"" + BODY_FIELD + "\":\"" + body + "\"");
      return new ResponseData(clones, responseData.getLogMessage());
  })
    .defaultIfEmpty(responseData);
}
```

As you can see I consume the original response body to get a `DataBuffer` used to create a cloned ClientResponse, which is then used in the filter to continue in the chain.

I do get the the actual response out of the client and I get the log message. Never the less there is an exception:

```
2022-05-13 09:47:36,530 | 10788 | httpclient-dispatch-1 | | ERROR | reactor.core.publisher.Operators | Operator called default onErrorDropped reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The client response body can only be consumed once.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The client response body can only be consumed once.
    at org.springframework.http.client.reactive.HttpComponentsClientHttpResponse.lambda$getBody$1(HttpComponentsClientHttpResponse.java:106)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Body from GET ... [DefaultClientResponse]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.http.client.reactive.HttpComponentsClientHttpResponse.lambda$getBody$1(HttpComponentsClientHttpResponse.java:106)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeek.java:162)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.reactive.ReactiveDataConsumer.subscribe(ReactiveDataConsumer.java:166)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSource.subscribe(FluxSource.java:67)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8469)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribeWith(Flux.java:8642)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8439)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8363)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8306)
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponseBuilder.releaseBody(DefaultClientResponseBuilder.java:195)
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponseBuilder.body(DefaultClientResponseBuilder.java:177)
        at com.netcetera.mobaint.utils.filter.message.BaseResponseMessageCreator.lambda$formatMessage$0(BaseResponseMessageCreator.java:39)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:113)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:295)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:159)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.reactive.ReactiveDataConsumer.flushToSubscriber(ReactiveDataConsumer.java:155)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.reactive.ReactiveDataConsumer.streamEnd(ReactiveDataConsumer.java:113)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.reactive.ReactiveResponseConsumer.streamEnd(ReactiveResponseConsumer.java:162)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.async.HttpAsyncMainClientExec$1.streamEnd(HttpAsyncMainClientExec.java:233)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.nio.ClientHttp1StreamHandler.dataEnd(ClientHttp1StreamHandler.java:280)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.nio.ClientHttp1StreamDuplexer.dataEnd(ClientHttp1StreamDuplexer.java:366)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.nio.AbstractHttp1StreamDuplexer.onInput(AbstractHttp1StreamDuplexer.java:333)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.nio.AbstractHttp1IOEventHandler.inputReady(AbstractHttp1IOEventHandler.java:64)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.nio.ClientHttp1IOEventHandler.inputReady(ClientHttp1IOEventHandler.java:39)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.decryptData(SSLIOSession.java:550)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.access$400(SSLIOSession.java:72)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession$1.inputReady(SSLIOSession.java:172)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.InternalDataChannel.onIOEvent(InternalDataChannel.java:131)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.InternalChannel.handleIOEvent(InternalChannel.java:51)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.SingleCoreIOReactor.processEvents(SingleCoreIOReactor.java:178)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.SingleCoreIOReactor.doExecute(SingleCoreIOReactor.java:127)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.AbstractSingleCoreIOReactor.execute(AbstractSingleCoreIOReactor.java:85)
        at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.IOReactorWorker.run(IOReactorWorker.java:44)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

This occurs on the `body` call upon the mutated response.

Is there any way to prevent this exception to occur or how would I be able to catch the exception so that it does no longer turn up as an error?

**Addendum:**

The root cause looks similar to [How to log request body in spring Webflux Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61706948/how-to-log-request-body-in-spring-webflux-java) which is true. However that issue is at the other end of the problem, where we are the server and get a request and return a response. This issue is about using the `WebClient` to make a request and receive the response. For that reason the proposed solution using a `WebFilter` is not applicable here - or at least I do not see how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to log request body in spring Webflux Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61706948/how-to-log-request-body-in-spring-webflux-java)

Comment: @Alex Not really as that one focuses on logging incoming requests (and possibly the responses). The issue I have here is when using a `WebClient` that sends out the requests and receives the responses.

Comment: From what I see the root cause is the same  - you are trying to consume body in filter and then in the client itself.