# How to transform between byte[] and Flux<DataBuffer>

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I need to read the request body before it gets consumed in biz logic.

So I'm planning to do below in my web filter:

1. transform Flux of DataBuffer into a byte[]
2. use the byte[] as I wish
3. attache a new Flux of DataBuffer which built on byte[] in step1 back to ServerWebExchange (with ServerHttpRequestDecorator)

I've checked thread like:
[How to log request body in spring Webflux Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61706948/how-to-log-request-body-in-spring-webflux-java)

But it seems to "get the request body when it gets consumed", while my case is to "get the request boy before it gets consumed".

That's why I need the bi-direction transformation between byte[] and Flux(DataBuffer).

I guess org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferUtils might be helpful, could anyone share some concrete code samples?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Because buffering data in memory is somehow against the reactive stack.

Comment: Also getting a `byte[]` means you have to `block` which is also against the reactive stack

Answer (score 1):

```
   DataBufferFactory bufferFactory = new DefaultDataBufferFactory();
    
   byte[] bytes = ....
   DataBuffer buffer = bufferFactory.allocateBuffer(bytes.length);
   buffer.write(bytes);
   return Flux.just(buffer);
```

Comment: should be a deferred logic here, can be blocking, etc